# Using React-Router-Dom, is there a way to re-direct a page on an event/function call rather than of using <Link ... /> and needing to press a button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to re-direct a page using react-router-dom without using a <link.. /> tag?

I want to change a page when a certain value that is held in state reaches 0. I was wondering if this this action can be automated rather than calling a link/button to change/re-direct the page?

Let me know If I need to clarify this statement any more?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. write a function inside useEffect with change in variable.Whenever the variable changes, useeffect will trigger and check if it reaches the required. When it reaches the required. Use "useHistory" hook then navigate to page you want.

```
const [value,setValue]=useState()
const history = useHistory()

useEffect(()=> {
 if (value==0) {
 history.push('/goal')
}
},[value])
```